# iOS: Does the app store reject apps built with older versions of swift?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an older app which has been hanging around for a while but now needs to be deployed to the app store. This app was last built with Xcode 10.1 and while it is primarily in Swift 4 it has some Swift 3 pods.

Someone has told me that apps submitted to the store which use Swift 3 will be rejected. Is there any evidence for this?

Comment: They don't care about what language it's written in they only care that you target the latest version of iOS. If you can compile your swift 3 code in a version of Xcode that can target iOS 12 you should be able to submit.

Comment: @Dare Thanks, if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now sent this app for review and it was accepted by the automatic validation process and by the Apple review, so evidently Swift 3 is still accepted by the store.

Answer (score 0):

The apple developer site (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/) only says that if you use Swift 4 you can upgrade your app to Swift 5 later on.
As there is nothing written about Swift 3 i assume that it´s an outdated version and not accepted anymore

"Xcode 10.2 includes Swift 5 and the latest SDKs for all Apple platforms. If your app is written in Swift, you can continue to submit apps in Swift 4 to the App Store and migrate individual modules to Swift 5 when you’re ready."

Comment: Given that that page doesn't mention Objective C either but ObjC apps are still accepted in the store, I'm not sure I can accept this answer. Do you have any other evidence?

Answer (score -1):

In Apple's Developer News: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122018c, it says that after March 2019 all App store submissions need to be built with the iOS 12 SDK.  Building with the iOS 12 SDK requires Xcode 10 or later.  IIRC, the minimum version of Swift supported for iOS builds using Xcode 10 in Swift 4.2.